# image stacking rendering different on chrome and ie9

Tags: html, css

I have two images and a jquery pic slider stacked on each other.  Basically three images stacked on each other.

Here is my code and here is how they are rendered.  Any ideas why?

```
 <a href='galeria.html'><img src='images/first.jpg' style='position:absolute' /><img src='images/second.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:100' /><div id='push' class='slideshow' style='z-index=-1'></div></a>
```

[image: Chrome rendering]
[image: IE9 rending]

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to define the coordinates also. Write like this:

```
img{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

Comment: didn't do it. It puts it way up top.

Comment: how you want side by side or one above an other ?

Comment: the white one with "liga juvenil de futbol" goes behind the "galeria de fotos" and then the slideshow goes in between them.  On top of the white one and behind the transparent one.